# CP210 driver installation on linux

Tags: makefile, kernel, driver

I have been unsuccessfully trying to install the CP210x drivers on my linux machine. The current version of kernel on my machine is 2.6.18.

Although I have heard, all kernel > 2.6.12 comes pre-loaded with CP210 drivers, I was unable to find one on mine, when I tried,

```
modprobe cp210x
```

It returned an error.

So when I tried to install the Cp210x driver from Silabs, I'm constantly ending with the following error,

```
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.18-194.8.1.el5/build 
M=/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source modules
make-3.79.1-p7[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.18-194.8.1.el5-x86_64'
CC [M]  /users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.o
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:45: warning: 'struct ktermios' declared inside parameter list
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:45: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:47: warning: 'struct ktermios' declared inside parameter list
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:175: error: unknown field 'usb_driver' specified in initializer
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:175: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:178: error: unknown field 'bulk_in_size' specified in initializer
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:178: warning: missing braces around initializer
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:178: warning: (near initialization for 'cp210x_device.driver_list')
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:178: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:179: error: unknown field 'bulk_out_size' specified in initializer
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:179: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:180: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:181: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:182: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:183: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:184: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:185: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:186: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:188: error: unknown field 'release' specified in initializer
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:188: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:189: error: unknown field 'dtr_rts' specified in initializer
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:190: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c: In function 'cp210x_open':
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:446: warning: passing argument 1 of 'usb_serial_generic_open' from incompatible pointer type
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:446: warning: passing argument 2 of 'usb_serial_generic_open' from incompatible pointer type
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c: In function 'cp210x_close':
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:453: error: too few arguments to function 'usb_serial_generic_close'
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:455: error: 'struct usb_serial' has no member named 'disc_mutex'
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:456: error: 'struct usb_serial' has no member named 'disconnected'
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:459: error: 'struct usb_serial' has no member named 'disc_mutex'
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c: In function 'cp210x_get_termios':
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:535: error: implicit declaration of function 'tty_encode_baud_rate'
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c: At top level:
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:702: warning: 'struct ktermios' declared inside parameter list
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:703: error: conflicting types for 'cp210x_change_speed'
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:45: error: previous declaration of 'cp210x_change_speed' was here
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c: In function 'cp210x_change_speed':
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:706: error: 'struct termios' has no member named 'c_ospeed'
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:720: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c: At top level:
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:729: warning: 'struct ktermios' declared inside parameter list
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:730: error: conflicting types for 'cp210x_set_termios'
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:47: error: previous declaration of 'cp210x_set_termios' was here
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c: In function 'cp210x_set_termios':
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:741: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:743: warning: passing argument 3 of 'cp210x_change_speed' from incompatible pointer type
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c: In function '__check_debug':
/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:1019: warning: return from incompatible pointer type
make-3.79.1-p7[2]: *** [/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.o] Error 1
make-3.79.1-p7[1]: *** [_module_/users/phunchik/Desktop/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source] Error 2
make-3.79.1-p7[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.18-194.8.1.el5-x86_64'
make-3.79.1-p7: *** [all] Error 2 **
```

It would be great if some one could help me fix this error or suggest a way to update my kernel

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your driver needs `Linux_3.x.x` as suggests the directory name.

For information, `Linux 3.x.x` is *equivalent* to `Linux 2.6.40+`. So you are *at least* 22 versions behind.

To upgrade your kernel, just use your distribution upgrade system (`apt-get`, `aptitude`, `yum`, ...).

You can also build a new kernel by hand, but it is far more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've just downloaded the wrong driver. The one for the 2.6 kernel is here:

http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/Software/Linux_2.6.x_VCP_Driver_Source.zip

hth